# Torque installation on RHEL 6.5

Tags: linux, redhat, torque, rhel6

I want to install TORQUE on a RHEL 6 single machine (32 CPUs).

I followed every instructions of the manual to install it, but I am facing an error in the end. Here are all the steps I followed:

First step, make sure that libxml2-devel openssl-devel gcc gcc-c++ are installed and up-to-date:

```
    # yum install libxml2-devel openssl-devel gcc gcc-c++
    Setting up Install Process
    Package libxml2-devel-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do
```

Then I downloaded and extracted the last version. Then I ran the default configure:

```
    # ./configure
```

I ran make and make install:

```
    # make
    # make install
```

With no errors.

I configured the trqauthd daemon to start automatically at system boot:

```
    # cp contrib/init.d/trqauthd /etc/init.d/
    # chkconfig --add trqauthd
    # echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/torque.conf
    # ldconfig
    # service trqauthd start
    Starting TORQUE Authorization Daemon: hostname: x6540
    Currently no servers active. Default server will be listed as active server. Error  15133
    Active server name: x6540  pbs_server port is: 15001
    trqauthd daemonized - port 15005
                                                       [  OK  ]
```

There is the first error there.

The error code means:

```
    PBSE_SERVER_NOT_FOUND   15133   Could not connect to batch server
```

I continued the installation until the end anyway, and I managed to start mom and server services, but finally end up with:

```
    # pbsnodes 
    localhost
         state = down
         np = 30
         properties = CIS
         ntype = cluster
         mom_service_port = 15002
         mom_manager_port = 15003
```

Can you help me? I can provide you with all logs/info needed.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just run **trqauthd** and **pbs_mom** as root in the client node.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error actually, it just tells you that it cannot find any active pbs_server process. Later when you start pbs_server process, everything will work as normal.

Or if you run "service pbs_server start" first, you will not see the error.